# Error: Use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, class, templates

When I try to run my program this error shows up "error C2955: 'FOURTEEN' : use of class template requires template argument list"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T, int n>
class FOURTEEN
{
private:
    T a[n];
public:
    void ReadData();
    void DisplayData();
};
void FOURTEEN::ReadData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        cin>>a.[i];
}
void FOURTEEN::DisplayData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        cin>>a.[i]<<'\t';
    cout<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    FOURTEEN <int, 5>P;
//Read data into array a of object P
    cout<<"Enter 5 numbers: ";
    P.ReadData();
//display data of array a of object P
    P.DisplayData();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to retype template somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Members of a template class are themselves templates parameterized by the parameters
of their template class. When such a member is defined outside its class, it must explicitly be
declared a template.

So you need change

```
void FOURTEEN::ReadData()
```

to

```
template <class T, int n>
void FOURTEEN<T, n>::ReadData()
```

And do the same thing to function `DisplayData`.

And there're some other errors:

In function `ReadData`, change

```
cin>>a.[i];
```

to

```
cin>>a[i];
```

and In function `DisplayData`, change

```
cin>>a.[i]<<'\t';
```

to

```
cout<<a[i]<<'\t';
```

Comment: Would making  ReadData()  inline help ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar You mean define it inside the class's defination? Yes.